# Using AdPlus with ASP.NET app need Process ID

Tags: .net, asp.net, adplus

I want to use AdPlus to diagnose out of memory errors.  To run the "hang" memory dump, I need to provide the process ID of my app.  What would that be and how do I go about finding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspnet_wp.exe process (or the W3wp.exe process on Windows Server 2003) 

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892277